# I want b2c custom policy to create a password before email is validated.?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a b2c custom policy that works correctly. We want customers to be able to create a password before their email is validated. Can someone show how such a custom policiy can be created?

It works when the customer creates a password after email is verified. We want to create the password before the email is verified

Answer (score 0):

If you look at "LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail", you see:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
```

so the password and email are in the same self-asserted Technical Profile.

You need to move the password fields to another self-asserted Technical Profile and then call that TP before you call the signup one in the user journey.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very good quick response. thanks